# MIPS - Add two single-precision floating-point numbers without using add.s

Tags: mips

The problem: calculate the sum of two float numbers (stored in `$f1` and `$f2`) without using built-in instruction `add.s`.

I tried searching around the web but there doesn't seem to be any hope. The most promising direction I found is to use bit shifting, but I'm totally new in that area.

What would be the best way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the manual addition of binary floating point numbers. Try to understand how it works and then write your instructions.

Comment: @AndiCover Thank you. So is that direction right? I understand how to do it manually, but I'm stuck at how to implement it. Like, how to get the components from those float number? Should I shift left 1 to get the exponent, and 8 more to get the fraction? But Idk what should I write to achieve it.